# Getting every second item from a tuple within a list of tuples

Tags: prolog

So I have recently started using prolog, since I am getting into using AI and FOL. I have noticed quite a few differences with other languages I have used such as Python and Java and I am having a difficult time trying to "compare" these languages.

The main problem I am having is that I have no idea how to build a rule to get a list of the second item of the tuples in a list.

The input is a list of tuples, for example: `[(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)]`.

I am trying to write a function such that the output is a LIST OF SECOND ITEM OF EVERY TUPLE within the list, namely [aa, bb, cc, dd]

I have already tried doing something along the lines of "`extract_second_item([(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], [(_ , output)|_])`". But when I run that function, it only returns the second item of the first tuple (`aa`) but apparently not the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: You should start with a Prolog tutorial !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a tuple is a compound:

```
?- write_canonical((a,b,c)).
','(a,','(b,c))
true.
```

so [arg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3)/3 is pretty functional to extract the second argument by position from a tuple:

```
?- arg(2,(a,b),X).
X = b.
```

the you can solve your problem in a compact way, using a [lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) expression

```
?- maplist([X,Y]>>arg(2,X,Y), [(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

Tuples aren't widely used in Prolog, indeed the problem has a simpler solution, directly applying pattern matching:

```
?- maplist([X,Y]>>(X=(_,Y)), [(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

Pattern matching could be pushed in the lambda arguments:

```
?- maplist([(_,Y),Y]>>true, [(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

Instead of library(yall), you could choose library(lambda), trading speed for portability:

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).
true.

?- maplist(\X^Y^(X=(_,Y)), [(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

In SWI-Prolog, this requires you install pack([lambda](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=lambda)),

```
?- pack_install(lambda).
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use simple recursion:

```
extract_second_item([], []).
extract_second_item([(_,X)|T], [X|T2]):- extract_second_item(T,T2).
```

Now querying:

```
?- extract_second_item([(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

Another great way proposed by @lurker is to use `maplist/3`:

Firstly we define a simple predicate that returns the second item from a tuple:

```
second_item((_,X), X).
```

Then we map second_item/2 to each tuple in the list using `maplist/3`:

```
?-maplist(second_item, [(1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc),(4,dd)], L).
L = [aa, bb, cc, dd].
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: This is an ideal application for `maplist`: `second_item((_,X), X).` then `maplist(second_item, Tuples, Items).`

Comment: Thanks @lurker, you have right this is the perfect example for maplist. Will you add an answer or should I add it in  the answer above ??

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer as an alternative solution. Your solution currently is a common Prolog pattern which is handled by `maplist`. Since the  OP is a beginner, the non-`maplist` solution is probably the most appropriate for their learning.